# How do I create a temporary file in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, temporary-files

In Java there exists the java.io.File.createTempFile function to create temporary files. In Groovy there doesn't seem to exist such a functionality, as this function is missing from the File class. (See: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html)

Is there a sane way to create a temporary file or file path in Groovy anyhow or do I need to create one myself (which is not easy to get right if I'm not mistaken)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
File.createTempFile("temp",".tmp").with {
    // Include the line below if you want the file to be automatically deleted when the 
    // JVM exits
    // deleteOnExit()

    write "Hello world"
    println absolutePath
}
```

### Simplified Version

Someone commented that they couldn't figure out how to access the created `File`, so here's a simpler (but functionally identical) version of the code above.

```
File file = File.createTempFile("temp",".tmp")
// Include the line below if you want the file to be automatically deleted when the 
// JVM exits
// file.deleteOnExit()

file.write "Hello world"
println file.absolutePath
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the above code snippet will create a new unique temp file each time it's being called.

Comment: @Tomato just suffered 20mins trying to understand why there is a whole bunch of numbers in my file name

Comment: Bonus points for the Groovy use of the `.with` closure to clean things up.

Comment: I down voted because it doesn't show how to obtain the newly created File object.  Without the file object I could not determine the path and could not make use of the temp file (I created a temp file for nothing).

Comment: @Benrobot I added a simplified version

Comment: Just came across this. Would you not just return the delegate from the `with`? Becomes - `File temp = File.createTempFile("temp",".tmp").with { write "Hello world"; println absolutePath; delegate }`

Comment: To input data to the file it's better to use some kind of writer: `.withPrintWriter { PrintWriter printWriter ->
    printWriter.println('the row')
}`

Answer (score 7):

You can use `java.io.File.createTempFile()` in your Groovy code.

```
def temp = File.createTempFile('temp', '.txt') 
temp.write('test')  
println temp.absolutePath
```

Answer (score 5):

The Groovy classes extend the Java file class so do it like you would normally do in Java.

```
File temp = File.createTempFile("temp",".scrap");
temp.write("Hello world")
println temp.getAbsolutePath()
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly, I totally overlooked trying the simplest solution instead of reading the reference...

Comment: All the JDK classes and methods are available in Groovy.